# Using content of members of a Struct in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

After excellent advice I defined a struct, filled it with data read from a file and pushed it on a vector. Nice!!! Could somebody tell me now how I can call back the content of a member of the i-th struct I pushed on the vector?

The Structure definition:

```
struct Config_Data
{
    int Surf_Index;
    std::string Surf_Mnemo;
    double Surf_Param[5];
    std::string Surf_Comm;
};
```

Instantiation of the Struct and the definition of the vector:

```
Config_Data SURF;
std::vector<Config_Data> CDATA_SURF;
```

For filling the struct:

```
for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    getline(INP_Stream, Line, delim_Config);
    SURF.Surf_Index=atoi(Line.c_str());

    getline(INP_Stream,SURF.Surf_Mnemo,delim_Config);
    SURF.Surf_Param[0]=Mnemo_list[SURF.Surf_Mnemo];
    for (j=1;j<=Mnemo_list[SURF.Surf_Mnemo];j++)
    {
        getline(INP_Stream,Line,delim_Config);
        SURF.Surf_Param[j]=strtod(Line.c_str(),NULL);
    }
    getline(INP_Stream, SURF.Surf_Comm,delim_Line);
    CDATA_SURF.push_back(SURF);
    cout<<CDATA_SURF.size()<<endl;
    string aaa=CDATA_SURF[i].Surf_Comm;
}
```

As you can see I read strings from a csv file. I am not so happy with the way I convert strings in the int or double types, but it seem to work.

The way I wanted to call the i-th struct in the vector and its member Surf_Comm:

```
std::string aaa=CDATA_SURF[i].Surf_Comm;
```

I compiled without problems but at runtime I get segment violation signals. Being a beginner, I have no clue what is going on.

All help is very welcome!!!

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: How do you fill `CDATA_SURF` with `Config_Data` instances? It seems that you use vector with incorrect size.

Comment: Show us the relevevant code. The structures you have look OK, I'm sure there's a bug in the way you use them.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the part where I fill the struct before the push_back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element numeration in `std::vector` starts with zero value. Thus if vector holds one element, index of this value is 0. In case of two values - 0 and 1 and so on. Do not be confused by the `size()` vector method. It returns a number of holding elements.

So index of the newly pushed value equals to `size()-1`. Access to i-th element (that does not exist) results into an error.

This code should work if you change range of `i` value in cycle to `for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )`.

Comment: Thanks, I modified in the code after the pushback i into i-1 and indeed it works. I thought I tested this already but without result. In any case problem solved!!! thanks a lot. Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the value of `i` is, it must be in the `std::vector`. That is, you must have put at least `i`+1 items in the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Can only reiterate: In this case you're pushing back an empty vector in a for loop and accessing the data within the same loop using `i`, so you must change it to`for(i=0; i<10; i++)`.

Otherwise, you're

1. Creating vector element 0 (the first element of the vector) with data , via a push_back
2. Reading vector element 1 (the second element of the vector) which does not exist until the next loop iteration. **Uh-oh, spaghetti-o's!**
3. segfault :)